# Bitmap of Windows Phone Control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to get a bitmap of a specific control in Windows Phone?
In WindowsForm applications this is possible with the DrawToBitmap method, but in Windows Phone there isn't a method like that.
What shall I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, using the `WriteableBitmap` class.

Let's say you have two controls, a button and an image:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Test" Click="Button1_Click" />
    <Image x:Name="Image1" />
</StackPanel>
```

And you want to generate a bitmap from the button, and assign it to `Image1`. Then just use the constructor of the WriteableBitmap that expects a UIElement, and assign your bitmap to the image control:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Creates a bitmap with a visual representation of the button
    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.Button1, null);

    // Assigns the bitmap to the image control
    this.Image1.Source = bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Can I also take an bitmap of an VideoElement?

Comment: @user2737037 I'm pretty sure it can, many augmented-reality apps are based on this

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! Do you know how the contents of a WebBrowser control can be captured. The code in the sample works but the image captured is just a white rectangle.